# Kendo UI - Multiselect com data source remoto

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Estou há dois dias quebrando a cabeça com o *multiselect do [kendo UI](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index)*. Sempre que retorno a lista com as informações da minha *action*, o plugin não consegue entender as informações e me retorna o seguinte erro: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. Já tentei transformar em array javascript, Json, e não vai de forma alguma. Segue o código javascript do plugin:

```
//Aplicar o filtro de Emails no campo de destinatários
$("#select-destinatarios").kendoMultiSelect({
    placeholder: "Selecione os destinatários...",
    dataTextField: "Email",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    autoBind: false,
    minLength: 3,
    filtering: function (e) {
        var filter = e.filter;
        if (!filter.value) {
            //prevent filtering if the filter does not value
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '../Alertbox/CarregarDestinatarios',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        filtro: $("#select-destinatarios").data('kendoMultiSelect').input.val(), tipoDestinatario: $("#slc-tipo-envio").val()
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

No servidor retorno uma `List<object>` com as propriedades `Email` e `Id` conforme mostrado no código abaixo:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filtro))
{
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    Alertas = usuario.FiltroDestinatario(filtro, Id, tipoDestinatario);
}
else
{
    Alertas = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}

foreach(var item in Alertas)
{
    ListaFinal.Add(new
    {
        Email = item.Key,
        Id = item.Value
    });
}

return Json(ListaFinal, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

O problema é que depois de tanto tentar ele funcionou com 1 registro. Quando trouxe mais, apresentou a mensagem de erro acima e mesmo trazendo somente um registro depois disso, a mensagem persistia.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: a função da propriedade data envia ao servidor e retorna o resultado para o data Source. Estranhamente, ele funciona uma coisa, não funciona outra, para tudo. E isso sem alterar uma linha de código. Talvez seja alguma confusão que ele está fazendo internamente já que o sistema está utilizando vários plugins. Aparentemente está funcionando agora. Obrigado.

Comment: Creio eu que se você colcoar  `data: function (data) { em` veze de  `data: function () {` e dar um console.log(data); você irá conseguir ver o retorno do seu servidor.